# What do I need to do to get a JS3 environment (or at least couchdb) up and running?

Tags: javascript, linux, couchdb

I'm primarily a front-end coder but I'm not a stranger to server-side programming or the command line. Regardless I've still got a lot to learn about setting up servers and whatnot so I was wondering if anyone could help me put together some steps for setting up CouchDB on (preferably) ubuntu.

That's my main goal but I'd also like to get the 'JS3' environment going if possible. [See this post](http://labs.mudynamics.com/2009/01/14/js3/) for more info.

The things I struggle with most are knowing what packages I need to install and how to get it so I can work in my browser on localhost. Thanks for any pointers you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are very dependant on the Operating System Flavor you use. On Freebsd you could go with

```
cd /usr/ports/www/helma ; make install clean
cd /usr/ports/databases/couchdb ; make install clean
```

and you have all the relevant software on your server. Then you need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) beeing hosted somewhere. Helma's Jetty Webserver can handle that for you.

For Ubuntu I read it now comes with a couchdb package sou you can just do

```
sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

Comment: now apt-get is something i know how to do :), thanks for the advice I'll give it a shot